# How to publish a jar application to Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, application-development

I want to upload a simple desk toy to the Ubuntu Software Center, I've researched and I can't seem to find the answer. Do I need to upload as .jar or .zip or .deb?? My jar file is an executable jar.  When I try to upload it it says "The upload does not appear to be a valid click package." on http://developer.ubuntu.com/

Side note: I am a Windows 7 veteran and its my first time using Ubuntu, these applications were made on eclipse in a Windows 7 PC and the executable runs on Ubuntu.

Comment: did you read this? http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/, BTW, if it says "click package" is very likely that you are trying to upload it for mobile, not for desktop.

Comment: Is the application specific to Ubuntu? If not, you could try to upload it to Debian, making it available to more people (it will get to Ubuntu, eventually). But it's a lot of work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you tried to upload file in the click apps tag . Use [this](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/new/) link to upload desktop apps